# How can I copy paste in the remote server?

Tags: linux, centos, osx

I use my mac connected to a remote server (Windows 2008) by Microsoft Remote Desktop beta, and in the remote server I use the WMware workstation created a virtual machine (CentOS 7.2).

In the virtual machine how can I paste my copy in the terminal?

I have tested use:<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd> +<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, ....and so on, can not paste success.

Comment: Tried middle click or right click? Both can be defined for copying (middle click e.g. in Linux MINT Distribution and right click e.g. in the PuTTy Tool)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves two non-Linux boundaries that need correct configuration for the desired operation to work. It should probably be asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the terminal the following might work:

- middle mouse click
- right click
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
- <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

Make sure to set the virual machine to allow shared/bidirectional clipboard in VMware. The shortcuts should be active in the OS you have focused, i.e. the one that is trapping all your keystrokes.

Comment: I tested all, do not work for me.

Comment: Well, you have two walls where it could fail: the windows remote connection and the VMware connection. I would test each separately.